# Pasar datos de un archivo.txt (java eclipse) a una Tabla mysql

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, mysqlconnector

Tengo que leer un fichero .txt (java-eclipse) y pasar su contenido a una BBDD, ya que tenía creada en MYSQL. **Como puedo hacer para que una linea se divida en cada uno de los campos que necesita la tabla**

**Cod Fichero Lectura**

```
public void leerFichero() {
        System.out.println("Leyendo fichero");
        BufferedReader leer = null;
        String linea;
        try {
            anidirAlumnoNuevo();
            leer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nombreFile));

            while ((linea=leer.readLine()) != null) {
                
                bbdd.insertarDatos(linea);
            }
            System.out.println("Se ha leido todo el texto");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                leer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

**BBDD**

```
package tarea11;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Result;

public class BBDD {
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Alumno12";
    public static final String USERNAME = "root";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "contrasenia";
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    Result res;

    public Connection getConection() {
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return con;

    }

    public void insertarDatos(String linea) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = getConection();
            String insert = "INSERT INTO alumno VALUES ('"+linea+"')";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(insert);


        

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Erro que me sale**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
at mysql.connector.j@8.0.31/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at mysql.connector.j@8.0.31/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at mysql.connector.j@8.0.31/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1334)
at mysql.connector.j@8.0.31/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2084)
at mysql.connector.j@8.0.31/com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
at tarea11.BBDD.insertarDatos(BBDD.java:41)
at tarea11.Fichero.leerFichero(Fichero.java:91)
at tarea11.Fichero.existeFichero(Fichero.java:42)
at tarea11.Main.opcionesMenu(Main.java:63)
at tarea11.Main.menu(Main.java:31)
at tarea11.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

**Estructura TABLA alumno**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Datos del archivo.txt**

> 1 osa p lo lo f c1 cu1 g1
> 3 se p de de f c3 cu3 g3
> 4 Juanquin Perez Losa M Primero Cuarto Cuarto

Comment: Revisa [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split\(java.lang.String\)). Si tu tabla tiene 7 columnas, debes enviar 7 valores en `VALUES` del `INSERT`, si no tienes todos los valores, pon el nombre de las columnas en el orden en que envías los valores.

Comment: Si, lo he estado probando con split() pero no me como hacer para que en el caso de 2 nombres o 2 apellidos no los separa y me dan fallos al momento de querer pasar los valores a los campos de la tabla. No se bien como pasarlos variable a viable o con un array, esa es mi duda.

Comment: En esos casos, es común que los nombres y apellidos compuestos estén entrecomillados, ej: `4 Juanquin "Perez Losa" M Primero Cuarto Cuarto`. Y la expresión regular para dividir podría ser: `" (?=([^\\\"]|\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*$)"`. Por otro lado si puedes cambiar el separador, por ejemplo `|`...